# AddressBook: how to get names of different Exchange sources

Tags: iphone, abaddressbook

I want to get the name of all the Exchange sources that my iPhone is synced to. For e.g. if I sync my device to Gmail and Hotmail accounts using ActiveSync Exchange, in the native contacts, I can see different sections based on the different accounts that I have setup. When I try to programmatically do the same, the only information I get is sourceType (which is Exchange in both cases) and sourceName (which is "Contacts" in both cases). There's no way for me to differentiate which is the Gmail "Contacts" and which is the Hotmail "Contacts".

Anyone know how to do this? Here's my code:

```
CFArrayRef allSources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(book);

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(allSources); i++) {
        ABRecordRef source = (ABRecordRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allSources, i);
        NSString *sourceTypeName = (NSString *)((CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(source, kABSourceNameProperty));
        NSLog(@"%@", sourceTypeName);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in iOS it seems (yet)